# Why is query isolation a good thing?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, sharding, horizontal-scaling

From the [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#query-isolation):

> Generally, the fastest queries in a sharded environment are those that
>   mongos will route to a single shard

That seems counter-intuitive to me. Isn't the whole point of sharding to spread the data and processing out horizontally, not vertically? Wouldn't it be faster if processing was done on multiple shards so that the processing is parallel?

Why is doing all your processing on one machine better than doing it on multiple machines in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As with all general statements, there are plenty of exceptions, but before we get to those, perhaps this would make more sense with a tweak to the wording:

> Generally, the fastest queries in a sharded environment are those that
>   mongos **can easily** route to a single shard

For a `mongos` to route a query to a single shard, then it will generally meet the following criteria:

- It will make use of the shard key
- Hence, it will be indexed (there is always an index on the shard key)
- It will have good data locality (all the data is on one shard)
- The query will return as quickly as that shard can respond
- If the majority of your queries look like this you will have a good shot of an in-memory hit on the index (at least)

This type of query will generally be faster, and if you have this type of query pattern (which a lot of people do), then the statement is basically correct.

However, if you are (for example) doing something computationally intensive which parallelizes well across a large data set (complex aggregation on a large data set), then splitting your work will definitely have advantages.

However, there are also potential downsides - the `mongos` will have to get results from all shards and potentially do some processing (imagine a sort split across shards), hence the result will only be as fast as the slowest shard (and possibly the `mongos`).

In the end it all depends on your workload, data distribution and how well you chose your shard key, but as a general statement it's not incorrect.

Comment: I still don't see though why it would be faster. Lets say the query I run a normal query (no aggregation framework stuff) and it returns 1M docs. Wouldn't it be better if it read 200k docs from 5 shards and 1M from 1 shard? Why would hitting a single shard be better in this case.

Comment: It could be faster, in particular if 200k represents the (near) maximum amount of documents you can fit in-memory on a single shard and hence you are essentially scaling out your available resident memory by sharding.  But, if you have to add that amount of preamble to your use case to justify it being faster, it really doesn't meet the requirements of a general statement.  For your use case, the statement may not apply at all, what the docs are giving are some guidance on the most common general query and usage patterns (as I outlined)

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why is splitting across shards not also better for cases with lets say just 1k docs - well below any memory limit. Yes a single shard can pull them quickly, but wouldn't it be faster if 5 shards pulled 200 each?

Comment: Usually because there is a cost to doing so and collating the results at the mongos - streaming results in an efficient manner (assuming order doesn't matter) through the mongos would reduce that cost, and there is a possibility of a slow shard, waiting for all results, potential latency.  Again, you may get results more quickly under some conditions when spread across shards, or you may not (especially if the potential delays are a large portion of the total time).  Best thing to do? Test your actual workload and find out what applies to you.